# npm install of angular project does not work (ECONNREFUSED on downloading xmlbuilder)

Tags: angular, npm, installation, proxy

I'm trying to clone one of my angular projects freshly. In order to make it work I have to do an npm install, which worked at some time. But now it fails with the following error:

```
npm install
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED    
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! FetchError: request to http://localhost:8080/xmlbuilder/-/xmlbuilder-11.0.1.tgz failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:97:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:376:20)
npm ERR!     at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:474:9)
npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (node:events:388:22)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:188:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:153:3)
npm ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21)
npm ERR!  FetchError: request to http://localhost:8080/xmlbuilder/-/xmlbuilder-11.0.1.tgz failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\index.js:97:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:376:20)
npm ERR!     at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:474:9)
npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (node:events:388:22)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:188:8)
npm ERR!     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:153:3)
npm ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21) {
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect',
npm ERR!   address: '127.0.0.1',
npm ERR!   port: 8080,
npm ERR!   type: 'system'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-08T10_06_22_381Z-debug.log
```

I have no proxy configured, nor do I need one. In fact he downloaded some packages until this error appears:

```
https-proxy = null
proxy = null
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

I've tried to install it manually, it works without problems.

```
npm install xmlbuilder
```

I've tried this as admin and elevated. No success.

So why isn't it installed as dependency? Where does he get this localhost:8080 address from? There is definitely no server listening.

Regards

Comment: Run 'set' to see if there are environment variables set -- for example, it could be picking up an HTTP_PROXY variable.

Comment: I'm on Windows Powershell. But the equivalent 'dir env:' shows nothing with Proxy in its name.

Comment: Maybe the powershell is picking up on a proxy set at the control panel/settings layer? Has it generated a c:\uesrs\eosgortor\.npmrc file with the proxy in there? Alternatively try 'npm config get proxy' to see if it shows anything?

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. For any reason these localhost:8080 was set at some lines in package-lock.json. Deleting node_modules and package-lock.json made npm install work again.